# The connection timed out after 3 sec while awaiting incoming data from bluk import apis

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, rabbit-mq, message-queue, bulk

I'm getting following error during use of bulk `async` import `apis`.

```
The connection timed out after 3 sec while awaiting incoming data
```

[image]

I've followed the magento dev docs for using for bulk import (Api)

```
**rest/all/async/bulk/V1/customers**
```

and getting above error

Following configuration we're using.

```
'queue' => [
        'amqp' => [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '15672',
            'user' => 'guest',
            'password' => 'guest',
            'virtualhost' => '/'
        ]
    ]
```

Ubuntu - 20.04
Host- localhost (installed rabbitmq-server on localhost )
magento - 2.4.2

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change port to "5672".
"15672" is for web interface

Answer (score 0):

I declared a queue from rabbitmq admin web interface 'my_queue', then I created a consumer with this code:

```
$callback = function ($msg) {
  echo ' [x] Received ', $msg->body, ""\n"";
};

$channel->basic_consume('my_queue', '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}
```

I started the consumer but this error appeared.

The connection timed out after 3 sec while awaiting incoming data

The issue was in the port where the client listening to it, it was set to "15672" while it should be "5672".

Port 15672 for rabbitmq web interface.

Port 5672 for rabbitmq client.